# Tensorflow Hub vs Tensorflow SavedModel?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I was wondering what is currently the recommended way to save models in Tensorflow?

[SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#build_and_load_a_savedmodel) or [Tensorflow Hub](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/)?

The former is described in the section "save & restore a model" but the latter seems to be described as the way to go for "reusable machine learning modules".

Furthermore, which one would be privileged in Tensorflow 2.0?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are different things. TF Hub provides you pretrained modules, you can reuse and retrain for new use cases, you can modify them as you please, and not have to retrain something from scratch. Think of transfer learning using Inception for example.

SavedModel is how you save a TF model, whether it's a new modified model using a TF Hub module, or something you created from scratch.

Hope that helps clear the confusion

Answer (score 0):

*what is currently the recommended way to save models in Tensorflow?*

saving or restoring models vs tensorflow hub are two completely different topics:

- TensorFlow Hub is a library for the publication, discovery, and consumption of reusable parts of machine learning models.
- Use SavedModel to save and load your model—variables, the graph, and the graph's metadata.

Sources: The links you provided.